# Positiveness of hard-core Coulomb potential energy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, potential, potential-energy

**EDIT:** I've modified the title to make it more specific.

In *On the $\nu$-Dimensional One-Component Classical Plasma: The Thermodynamic Limit Problem Revisited* by Sari and Merlini (**Journal of Statistical Physics, 14, 2, 1976**), the authors derive at some point $H$-stability for the two-dimensional Coulomb gas (i.e. 2D Jellium) confined on some domain $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, *i.e.*
$$
\underbrace{-\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq N} \log|x_i - x_j|}_{particles-particles} + \underbrace{\sum_{i}\int_{\Lambda} \log|y - x_i|\text{d}y}_{particles-background} - \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\iint_{\Lambda \times \Lambda} \log|x - y| \text{d}x \text{d}y}_{background-background} \geq -NC,
$$
for some constant $C \leq 0$. To do so, they use a strategy proposed by Onsager in 1939 (*Electrostatic Interaction of Molecules* **Journal of Physical Chemistry, 43, 2, 1939**), which consists in replacing the point charges by charge distributions smeared into disks of radius $a$. Let us write $H_{bb}$ for the background self-energy (i.e. the term on the far right above), $H_{ij}$ for the interaction between the disks $B(x_i, a)$ and $B(x_j,a)$, and $H_{i}$ the interaction between $B(x_i,a)$ and the background. Now, the authors claimed that this quantity
$$
H_{bb} + \sum_{I} H_i + \sum_{i \neq j}H_{ij}
$$
is << **obviously positive** >>. My questions are:

- Why is this << obviously >> positive from a physical perspective (PS: I'm not a physicist)
- Is it obvious mathematically ? (It doesn't seem to me)
- Bonus : can someone explain the idea behind Onsager strategy ?

Thanks a lot for any kind of help !

Comment: What is $B(x,a)$?

Comment: Sorry ! $B(x,a)$ is the "ball" (i.e. the disk in 2D) of center $x$ and radius $a$.

Comment: It is not obvious.

Comment: Does Theorem 9.8 in [this book](https://b-ok.cc/book/1113424/4b7ac4) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But it seems Lieb & Loss prove it for $n \geq 3$. When $n = 2$, it seems slightly more complicated, see (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150497/positivity-of-the-coulomb-energy-in-two-dimensions), which tend to make me believe that not only this is mathematically not obvious, but it's also very false... Do you have the physical intuition on why this is "true" ?

Comment: No, I have no intuition about that. :)